# Internet connection drops out

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04, internet, network-manager

I have this random network failure. No error pops up, the system says it's still connected to the internet(wifi and wired).
The problem is, I can't connect to anything, even a ping google.com gives no feedback. 
This only affects eth0, wifi is still working correctly, the cable and the port are fine.
I know this because when I boot my device, it is connected to the internet, skype logs in, but when I want to open a connection to anything else(browser, vm, ping or whatever) it drops out, saying it is still connected and no errors.

I noticed that the /etc/resolv.conf contains this line:

> nameserver 127.0.0.1

I had a random 3 sec connection, after which it dropped out again, and this line was added in the resolv.conf

> search lan

When I change the nameserver to 8.8.8.8, I am still unable to connect to anywhere.

Does anyone got a clue what is happening here?
I will provide any information asked.

Thanks in advance

p.s. I run Ubuntu 13.04, and started after upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04

Comment: You write "When I change the nameserver to 8.8.8.8, I am still able to connect to anywhere." Did you mean to say "I am still UNable to connect"?

Comment: @jdthood woops, yes I meant that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One known bug that could be affecting you is this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1003842

Try disabling the local forwarding nameserver. In NetworkManager.conf

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

or

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq`

```
#dns=dnsmasq
```

and save the file and restart NetworkManager.

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

Comment: Aren't we supposed to use gksudo for graphical things that use sudo? Not that it works differently

Comment: The gksu package isn't installed by default. But I will edit the answer to mention it because gksudo seems to be preferred for launching graphical applications with root privs.